# External variable declarations not working in C++ (crashing with header file)

Tags: c++

I have been programming a code to simulate some conduction transfer problems but I am stuck on the generation of the mesh. This is because I may be using the declarations of the variables wrong...
MAIN:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "library.h"
using namespace std;

int main (void){
    // Number of divisions
    int xdivA, xdivB, ydivA, ydivB, ydivAB;
    xdivA=30; xdivB=30; ydivA=30; ydivB=30; ydivAB=30;
    int N=xdivA+xdivB;
    int M=ydivA+ydivB+ydivAB;
    struct controlvolume celln[N][M];
}
```

Header file:

```
//GLOBAL VARIABLES
extern int N;
extern int M;

//STRUCTURE TYPES
    struct prop {
        double rho, Cp, k;
    };
    struct points {
        double x, y;
    };
    struct controlvolume {
        points coord;
        prop localmaterial;
    };

// FUNCTIONS
double Mesh(controlvolume celln[N][M], int xdivA, int xdivB, int ydivA, int ydivB, int ydivAB,  points initialp[4], prop materials [4]);
```

Mesh.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "library.h"
using namespace std;

double Mesh(controlvolume celln[N][M], int xdivA, int xdivB, int ydivA, int ydivB, int ydivAB, points initialp[4], prop materials[4]){
    celln[2][2].coord.x=initialp[3].x;
    celln[2][2].localmaterial.rho=materials[2].rho;

}
```

All the variables used such as initialp,materials, etc. are declared in the main function. I did not include them here to save space.

The error that I am getting is:

[Error] array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token

[Error] array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token

[Error] expected ')' before ',' token

[Error] expected unqualified-id before 'int'

It appears to be in the library.h file, when the function Mesh is defined...

I appreciate your help!!!
:)

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the dimensions of an array must be compile-time constants. This, for example :

```
 int N=xdivA+xdivB;
```

is not a constant of any sort, so you need to define it as one:

```
 const int N=xdivA+xdivB;
```

Similarly, for the other variables in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an array with dynamic size in C++. `celln[N][M]` - `N` and `M` have to be known at compile time. Change `N` and `M` to compile time constants or use something like a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

The size of an array must be a known constant at compile-time. You'll get an error if that is not the case

```
N=xdivA+xdivB; // This declaration should change to

const int N=xdivA+xdivB;
```

If you wish to have a variably-sized array whose size is determined later on, consider using `std::vector`, which can be resized at runtime.